Strictly positive definite kernel if all eigenvalues positive in Hilbert-Schmidt expansion?
Suppose I have a positive-definite kernel $K:X^2\to\mathbb{R}$. Mercer's theorem says there is a complete orthonormal system $\{\phi_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ for $L^2(X)$ such that each $\phi_i$ is an eigenfunction of the Hilbert-Schmidt integral operator of the kernel.
I want to show that if all eigenvalues of this operator are strictly positive, then the kernel is strictly positive-definite.
In particular, I believe it suffices to show that a strict version of Mercer's condition holds: for all $f\in L^(X)$, we have that
$$\iint_{X\times X} f(x) K(x,y) f(y) dx dy > 0.$$
This seems obvious to me but I have never seen it stated so I think I may be missing a technicality. I would like to see if this proof is correct.
Let $f$ be an arbitrary element of $L^2(X)$. Then $f$ has a Fourier expansion
$$f\sim \sum_{i=1}^\infty f_i \phi_i$$
on a Hilbert basis $\{\phi_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ of $L^2(X)$.
Suppose $K(x,y)$ is a positive-definite kernel on $X\times X$ with Hilbert-Schmidt expansion
$K(x,y) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \lambda_i \phi_i(x)\phi_i(y)$ and all $\lambda_i > 0$.
We compute the integral of Mercer's condition:
$$\int_{X\times X} K(x,y) f(x) f(y) dx dy = \int_X \left(\int_{X} K(x,y) f(x) dx\right) f(y) dy.$$
By the orthonormality of the Hilbert basis, we can write
$$\int_X \left( \sum_{i=1}^\infty \lambda_i \phi_i(y) \left(\int_{X} \phi_i(x) \sum_{j=1}^\infty f_j \phi_j(x) dx\right)\right) f(y) dy = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \lambda_i f_i \int_X  \phi_i(y)\left(\sum_{j=1}^\infty f_j \phi_j(y) \right) dy = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \lambda_i f_i^2,$$
which is $>0$ unless all $f_i=0$. Thus if the Mercer's condition integral is not strict for some $f\in L^2(X)$, then $f=0$. This shows that $K$ is strictly positive definite.
Is this proof correct? Thanks.
